# Is there a way I can change where a PHP page selects from a MYSQL database by using a form?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a website and I want to make it easier for someone to change certain information being shown without them having to edit the HTML/PHP and using FTP.

At the moment I have this information in a php file which is included in the MYSQL query.

It would be a lot easier if this was done using a form, say a text field where a person can type the table name and it updates on the main page and starts displaying that table instead.

Sorry if I haven't explained this well. :(

Comment: I don't think you did well in your explanation. Are you looking at a user-friendly way of changing the content on a web page? If so, you could look at a content management system.

Comment: so many guys are joining stackoverflow recently... which are the % rate growth'

Answer (score 1):

I have a good news for you.
Every php/mysql-driven site in the world is made this exact way - to edit site contents using HTML form.

Even first PHP version name was PHP/FI, stands for Form Interpreter.

Even better, a site user doesn't have to deal with mysql - it's all being done in PHP. No need to type table names into form field - all table names already written in PHP code.

Usual PHP application being connected to just one mysql database - so, no need to choose.
As for the tables, it's being done this way: a user selects some *human-readable* matter, like "Latest news" and being redirected to the PHP script called, say, `news.php`. this script runs a query for the `news` table in the database and outputs some HTML formatted news highlights!

Even more, you don't even need to program! There are plenty of ready-made programs, such as [Wordpress](http://wordpress.org)

Answer (score 0):

1. store what you want to be editable in a mysql text field.
2. remove tags you dont want him to see
3. in the form echo the editable information in a textarea
4. have him edit
5. add tags
6. update the mysql

note depending on the users knowledge depends on how many tags you would like to remove/add. the less per a field the easier.

on more complicated things i like to have the person log in. if he has permission then all the editable fields have an edit button. if he clicks it it goes to a page with a form that he can use to edit that 1 field